# Monitoring : Centreon - How to connect centreon user to database?

Tags: mysql, database, apache2, monitoring, centos6

I'm running Centreon Entreprise Server (CES) 3.3 and added NagVis (1.8.x). They are on a virtual machine (Virtualbox).

When I suceeded in giving the rights to NagVis to reach my Centreon data, Centreon started displaying : "Database error: Could not connect to database", though **the centreon user has all privileges on "centreon" and "centreon_storage"**.

Here's my central-broker-master.log :

`[1467987167] error: storage: rebuilder: could not connect to Centreon Storage database: could not open database: Access denied for user 'centreon'@'localhost' (using password: YES) QMYSQL: Unable to connect
[1467988484] error: TCP: error while sending data to peer 'localhost:5670': The remote host closed the connection
[1467988492] config: module applier: loading directory '/usr/share/centreon/lib/centreon-broker'
[1467988492] config: correlation: invalid correlation configuration, correlation engine is NOT loaded
[1467988492] config: applier: 14 modules loaded
[1467988492] error: could not open database: Access denied for user 'centreon'@'localhost' (using password: YES) QMYSQL: Unable to connect
[1467988492] error: TCP: could not connect to localhost:5670: Connection refused
[1467988492] error: could not open database: Access denied for user 'centreon'@'localhost' (using password: YES) QMYSQL: Unable to connect`

(the last error is written hundreds of times ...)

And I couldn't find other errors in different logs. (Or wasn't able to find the right logs ...)

The 'centreon' user has the rights on the databases with the IP address of my server as well as with my coputer's address. (This could have been a matter of rights from a distant location)

I don't know any other way to grant my 'centreon' user with extra rights on the database -- Is it even a valid idea to grant my user with all privileges ?

Thanks

EDIT : I tried to solve the problem by using this post : [MySQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bill'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw) (I actually had a ''@'localhost' user), but my access to Centreon web is still denied.